Blazorise Component containing Scrollable table using remaining height
Using Blazorise I would like to create a scrollable table with a fixed header and footer section.  Although I can see how to do by specifying a fixed height on the table, I would like the height of the table to vary based on the remaining height in the component.
The Table allows using calc() for FixedHeaderTableMaxHeight
but not for FixedHeaderTableHeight: FixedHeaderTableMaxHeight="calc(100% - 100px)"
Also, confusingly setting FixedHeaderTableHeight larger than 300 does not work unless FixedHeaderTableMaxHeight is adjusted as it defaults to 300px (I verified this using browser dev tools)
<Container Position="Position.Fixed.Top">
    Header
</Container>

<div style="border-style:solid; max-height:calc(100% - 100px); overflow:hidden" >
    <Table Bordered FixedHeader FixedHeaderTableMaxHeight="calc(100% - 100px)" FixedHeaderTableHeight="600px" Style="overflow:auto">
        <TableHeader >
            <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(50)">#</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(100)">Column 1</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(150)">Column 2</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(100)">Column 3</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(450)">Column 4</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(230)">Column 5</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(220)">Column 6</TableHeaderCell>
                <TableHeaderCell Width="@Width.Px(200)">Column 7</TableHeaderCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody >
            @for (int i = 1; i <= 30; ++i) {
                var index = i.ToString();

                <TableRow @key="@index">
                    <TableRowHeader Width="@Width.Px(50)" >@index</TableRowHeader>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(100)">Column 1</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(150)">Column 2</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(200)">Column 3</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(450)">Column 3</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(230)">Column 4</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(220)">Column 5</TableRowCell>
                    <TableRowCell Width="@Width.Px(200)">Column 6</TableRowCell>
                </TableRow>
            }
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
</div>

<Container Position="Position.Fixed.Bottom">
    Footer
</Container>


I believe the problem I had was using 100% instead of 100hv where 100% is 100% of the parent but using 100vh seems to do what I want and limit the size of the Table
